# want to add record vertically in database

Tags: asp.net, database

I am making attendance management system in which I have to record the time in and time out of an employee several times a day.

This can easily be achieved if I add a new row for every timein and time out.
But the problem is that the number of employees is very high, so
I want to add `timein` and `timeout` horizontally rather than vertically.

How that can be done?
e.g

> id | Barcode | date | time in | time out | time in | time out| .......
>   | total time

Comment: From a database logic standpoint your request is wrong. Add records for each in/out event and let the database handle the 'excess rows'

Comment: Not sure how and why you want to do it in this way but definetly not a good design for any db. If MAX number times an employee can do IN and Out is fixed then u can think of making them in cols else it should always be in rows. 
Once again why are you afraid of making them in rows even if there are huge number of employees?

Comment: actually i am making and application that can handle 90k users so if i create 5-10 rows for every employee than the database cant handle that

Comment: r u kidding me....ur db is not able to handle only 90k * 10 rows < 1 million rows? hv u tried? Which db u r using?

Comment: MSSQL ihave no idea regarding this but boss said it is possible

Comment: It's better you would ask your boss instead of Stackoverflow .

Comment: by MSSQL do u mean SQL Server? If yes then believe me it should not have any problem in handling records in millions. I have handled enterprise application dbs with records upto 10-20 millions in various tables and know other frnds who hv db tables with 100 million records and more. However you might hv to crete your indexes properly and upto date in order to make sure your select queries work fast. Also if data grows a lot, think of Archiving data periodically (based on your requirements and design) using some batch jobs.

Comment: what if i make only 2 columns time in and out
and every time a user time in/out i append it to previous value using commas and when calculating total time put that values in array and do the rest of manupulation

Comment: Such work arounds can work if u r just using in/out time for display..... Think of scenario if u hv to do put ur in/out time in any where or group clause of any queries like get all users who came after 10 am in last few days.....or Get count of users who comes between 8-9, 9-10 and so on...

Comment: Is that 90k * 10 rows... overall, or every day or week or what?

Comment: A million rows a day does seem like a pretty high volume. But as long as your table is indexed properly (say you only query by employee and put an index on the employee column), you shouldn't have that many rows per employee to deal with. You could also consider archiving the data every so often.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the Comments that you should keep the data in a vertical fashion because it is a better design and utilizes the "relational" aspect of the database.  Based on your description of the system having approximately 90,000 employees and may 5-10 rows per employee in the table (90k * 10 ).... you should consider having an Index on the employee id field (FK) so that your queries are more efficient.  By using an Index, you shoudl be able to store many records and not see any speed issues.